# Delete all records from table - doCMD.RunSQL

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am looking to clear a local table of all records before adding new data to it. I am trying to do this using the doCMD.RunSQL command but keep receiving run time error I am guessing because of its placement within the open connection, I am unsure on how to get this to execute.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

```
Sub GetUsers()
    Dim oConnection As Object
    Dim oSheet As Object
    Dim oCell As Object
    Set oConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Dim strDBPath As String
    strDBPath = "C:/Users/stevemcco/Desktop/Users.accdb"
    Dim sConn As String
    sConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                        "Data Source=" & strDBPath & ";" & _
                        "Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;" & _
                        "Persist Security Info=False;"

    oConnection.Open sConn

    DoCmd.RunSQL "Delete * from Table1"

    For Each oSheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        For Each oCell In oSheet.Columns(1).Cells
            If oCell.Value = "" Then
                Exit For
            End If

            If (oCell.Row > 1) Then 'Jumps the header
                oConnection.Execute " Insert Into Table1(ID,Area) " _
                & " VALUES ('" & oCell.Value & "','" & oSheet.Name & "')"
            End If

        Next
    Next
    oConnection.Close
    Set oConnection = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: There is no DoCmd object in Excel.

Comment: I had to add reference for MS DAO 3.6 object library to make it visible. Still couldn't get it to work mind you.

Answer (score 2):

for local database you would use: `CurrentDb.Connection.Execute "DELETE * FROM Table1"`

In your case use: `oConnection.Execute "DELETE * FROM Table1"`

Comment: If I wanted to query this new table data and return any duplicates onto my main excel sheet how would I go about this?